# How can I use Darboux theorem to prove that the absolute value function in not differentiable at 0?

Tags: calculus

To prove it in this logical way:

If a then b

not b

therefore not a.

?

Answer (score 0):

You know the derivative of the absolute value function on $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. It takes only the values $\pm 1$.

The derivative at the point $0$ can only add one single value to the image of $f'$ (if it exists at all).

But a function taking at least two different values which also fulfils the intermediate value theorem has to attain uncountably many values.